# Heroku and realtime

Tags: heroku

I wrote a Django application, which I deployed on Heroku. Now I have to add a real-time function, and I can not find any advice on using socket.io and node.js or django channels. Advices?

Comment: [Finally, Real-Time Django Is Here: Get Started with Django Channels](https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django) ?

Comment: I read this article but Is there some cons and pros about django channels vs socket.io?

Comment: idk tbh - however, that question different to what you posted. that would be a better suited for stackoverflow